# sometimes the error "yii the table for active record class cannot be found in the database"

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii

I never had this problem before last Friday!
Lately (last Friday and Saturday) from some pc which surf this page appears this error: **the table "devices" for active record class "Devices" cannot be found in the database**
I have seen that is a frequent problem but I did not understand how to solve this issue.
In my Devices model I have the correct table name

```
public function tableName()
{
    return 'devices';
}
```

And in my **MySQL** database the name is the same, *devices*

Comment: This can be many things, are you using a dynamic database connection perhaps?

Comment: I use a MySQL database. What do you mean with "dynamic connection" ?

Comment: The strange thins is that only from some pc appears this error

Comment: I only have one MySQL database

Comment: Does it happen in specific cases? On specific queries or something

Comment: the query are generated randomly each day but is always the same pc that generates this error.